# VMware Player - Private Network configuration

Tags: networking, vmware

I have 3 VM's, connected on the same private network, let's say A, B and C.
If would like to sniff on B, what A sends to C.
I've set B into promiscuous mode, but i don't get anything from A or C.
But if I send and ARP request from A to C, I see it on B.
It seems that there is a switch or something like that on VMware.
Do you know if it is possible to disable it or change it's configuration?

Comment: When using a hardware or software switch (bridge), unicast packets from A to B are not seen by C. That's by design. ARP packets are often sent as multicast packets, that's why you see them.

Comment: Ok, but is it possible to replace the software switch by a hub?

Comment: It's possible to use "port mirroring" with managed switches. Allowing to capture all traffic on the switch port #i, on which A is plugged. I don't know if the equivalent exist for your hypervisor.